# BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices - seems not to merge all identical vertices in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a weird issues with BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices method

I took a simple cube from a jsfiddle and performed the mergeVertices and it seems mergeVertices does not merge all identical vertices as it should. See https://jsfiddle.net/tomfree/vpdwmycn/

E.g. the vertices given in the indexGeometry returned by mergeVertices are

```
Index 0 = (-1, -1, 1, )
index 1 = (1, -1, 1,)
index 2= (-1, 1, 1, )
index 3= (1, 1, 1,)
index 4= (1, -1, 1)
```

i.e. vertices at position 1 and 4 seem to be the same but shouldn't after mergeVertices to my understanding. I am pretty sure that I am missing sth. Can someone point me into the right direction?

Cheers
Tom

ps: Also posted as https://discourse.threejs.org/t/buffergeometryutils-mergevertices-seems-not-to-merge-all-identical-vertices/33890 in three.js forum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The merge process is functioning as expected. If you look at the count of each attribute of the original `geometry` you'll get 36, but if you look at the count of each attribute of the merged `indexedGeo`, you'll get 24:

```js
console.log(geometry.getAttribute("position").count);    // 36
console.log(indexedGeo.getAttribute("position").count);  // 24
```

The problem you're encountering is that the merge method looks at **all** attributes before merging. In your case, `position, normal, uv`. The corners of a box have 3 vertices, each with its own normal pointing in 3 directions (one pointing up, one right, and one forward, for example). Since each vertex contains unique `normal` data on how to render its respective face, these vertices cannot be merged.  Even though their position is the same, the other attributes are different.

Comment: Thanks. Makes total sense. I was too focussed on purely the positions